# Extracting a very particular color from an orthomosaic and eventually making a vector

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm working on an orthomosaic and there is a particular weed species that is flowering at the moment and I need to isolate it and map it out. It's a yellowish green and is obvious in the ortho. I know there must be a way to isolate it so I can map it better.

I've tried the raster calculator with the following expression:

```
Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1"=190-210 AND "Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2"=210-225 AND "Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3"=78-86
```

I've made this a range of colors to try and best capture the range that this flower reflects.

The information shown when I use the "information" pointer is the following:

- Band 1 = 210
- Band 2 = 218
- Band 3 = 83

What am I doing wrong as the other answers on this site don't seem to cover this type of question well.

I'll eventually make a vector shapefile layer out of it.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

your syntax is wrong, use something like:

```
(("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1">=190) AND ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1"<=210)) 
AND (("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2">=210) AND ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2"<=225)) 
AND (("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3">=78) AND ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3"<=86))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, I ran your expression and it didn't seem to work. I had a black and white output of "0" each, not sure why as this weed grows prevalent. Is there a filter to apply after this to view it? Thanks

Comment: the output is true (1) or false (0).

Comment: @Nathan_Litjens : You can multiply the black/white (0/1) raster with your original raster (or the three bands of your raster) to get a new raster with only those pixsels you selected. If you do it sperately for each band, you can than merge the three outputs together to get a color-raster with only the pixels in the value-range defined.

Comment: My issue is that I got all 1 or all 0. I'll try the suggestions below and get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a new raster in *Raster Calculator* - call it MASK

```
("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1">=190) *("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1"<=210) * ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2">=210) *("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2"<=225) * ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3">=78) * ("Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3"<=86)
```

This will give you a single band raster as a mask - it will be 1 when you have the right colour, and 0 otherwise. You can convert that to vector.

You can also apply it as a mask to the original data to make 3 bands, band by band, again in the *Raster Calculator*:

```
"Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@1" * Mask@1
"Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@2" * Mask@1
"Narlu Orthomosaic 26-06-21@3" * Mask@1
```

This creates three more rasters. Combine these to a new raster file with **Raster-Miscellaneous-Merge**, placing each file into a separate band.

Set the transparency of the new raster file to 100% for pixels with value 0. You should then see only your weed plantation. This can be done interactively in the *Layer Styling Panel*.

There are probably more elegant ways of doing this. There may be plugins that do it all.